# Why we cannot divide a point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a point of $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $m>1$?

Tags: real-analysis

I've read Munkre's Analysis on Manifolds, and when the book was trying to define differentiation of function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$. It said we cannot simply use the definition of differentiation on function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, since the reason in title. But why we cannot divide two point when $m>1$ and why we can when m equal to 1? Thanks!

Comment: how do you think such a division would go if you think it is possible? When $m = 1$, the division is not by a point, but a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways of actually defining the derivative in 1D. The simple way is any function denoted $f'(x)$ which satisfies:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-hf'(x)}{h}$$

The usefulness of this is that $h$ is a scalar, for a vector function:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{x})-A\mathbf{h}\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}}{\|\mathbf{h}\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}}=0$$

So you're not dividing by points in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ but by scalars.